# Using relationships correctly in stackmob

Tags: relationship, stackmob

I'm looking to do a very simple chatroom / messaging centre using stackmob but i'm unsure of the best way to use my schemas / relationships to ensure data permissions etc.

So far i have:

```
Schema - Chatroom:
fields - chatroom_id
         sm_owner
         createddate
         lastmoddate
relationships - author - one to one - user
                members - one to many - user
                messages - one to many - message

permissions - read - allow to members relationship


Schema - Message
fields - message_id
         message
         createddate
         lastmoddate
relationships - author - one to many - user

permissions - ?
```

My issue:

I would like to set the permissions of the message to only allow read access to the users who are classed as members in the chatroom that has the relationship with this message.

How can i know which chatroom is attached... the relationship is set on the chatroom not the message schema.

Is there another approach that I should take?

Thanks